# Implementing a horizontal parallax scroll in React app, Need recommendations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, frontend

I have been tasked with creating a horizontal, parallax-esque, scrolling experience similar to this (I'm aware that this isn't exactly great UX) https://homesociete.ca/ or https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/ .

So far I have attempted to recreate this using react-id-swiper (a react implementation of swiper.js). Using freemode, I was able to meet the MVP of this component but it lacks the tools necessary to add all the bells and whistles required (specifically I would like to be able to bind scroll progress to various animations).

If anyone could recommend a library or a strategy for implementing something similar I would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out the [react-scroll-parallax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-parallax) npm package.